# How to install Parse Server on Heroku?

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, parse-platform, parse-server

How can Parse Server be installed on Heroku using the [parse-server](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server) repository and not the [parse-server-example](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server-example) repository?

I cloned parse-server locally and was trying to modify the `start` script in `package.json` but without success. I still want to use an index.js file like in parse-serverexample to configure the server.

Comment: Just go to Heroku dashboard and set up to accept your own source and upload to Heroku.

Comment: @thailey01 that I know and I managed to deploy the parse server example package to heroku via git push. But i don't know how to deploy the local copy of a parse-server package instead of the example package.